# nginx not serving CSS or JS

Tags: php, docker, nginx, webserver

I don't have any idea how nginx configs work, but I have this pulled from another project i've been working on, and that one is able to load CSS and JS without a hitch. This questions does get asked a lot, but it's hard to grasp from my particular case what I need to do as most of the answers are specific to that users nginx file!

My new project uses docker-compose and sets the nginx conf file from my local project. Definitely works as the PHP pages are loading fine. I get 404s on all css and js files (and anything else not .php).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    client_max_body_size 12M;

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

This is my super rudimentary nginx file. I have two containers in my docker project, one as web (nginx:latest) and app (php:7.4-fpm-buster). What is it missing that is causing my other files not to load?

As this works in my other application, I cannot see what is missing!

Thanks :)

Comment: I had a problem like this with Symfony 4. Did you use Symfony ?

Comment: I'm using Laravel actually so not dissimilar, but it won't be related to the framework. If nginx isn't serving css it'll be a the nginx level for sure. I have index.php in public/ and it's bootstrapping the framework fine. Seeing as the application runs from public/ then the app.css file should load in fine (public/css/app.css). It 404s with the correct url so it must be nginx here.